# Change style as per the text size in select dropdown tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code is as below. As per the text size I want to change the width of `DIV`. Like if the max text length of select option is more than 100 then change the width of parent div to 240px and also change the width of select tag.

```
<div class="products">
  <select>
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
    <option>Test Test Test Test Test </option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

javaScript I tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('.products select option').each(function(){

    var maxLength = jQuery(this).val().length;
    console.log(maxLength);

  });

  // if max length is greater than 50 then increase the width of the div 250px


});
```

Example **[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/urejey/3/edit)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering mechanism of a select box is, It takes the by default the max Length. Suppose In your example when select box find "Test Test Test Test" select box takes its length.

To achieve what you want you can write following.

Your jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('.products select option').each(function(){

    var maxLength = jQuery(this).val().length;
    if(length > maxLength){
      $('.products select,.products').css("width","250");
    }

  });

  // if max length is greater than 50 then increase the width of the div 250px


});
```

Your Html Markup would be :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  .products{
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;

  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>

  <div class="products">
  <select>
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
    <option>Test Test Test T Test Test T Test Test T </option>
  </select>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var maxLength = 0;
  jQuery('.products select option').each(function(){

    var length = jQuery(this).val().length;
    if(length > maxLength) {
      maxLength = length;
    }

  });
  if(maxLength > 100) {
    $(".products").css("width", "240px");
    $(".products select").css("width", "250px");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code into the each-loop:

```
if (maxLength > 100) {
  $('.products,.products select').width(240);
}
```

Also see your [updated exmaple](http://jsbin.com/urejey/4/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is have a class rule for the parent div and select so all you have to do is add a class to the parent div

```
jQuery('.products select option').each(function(){

    if( maxlength > 50 ){
         $(this).closest( '.products').addClass('wide_240');

          return false;  // break each loop

     }


})
```

Not sure which values you want.... one place says 50 max and 240px, other place says 100 max and 250px

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

http://jsbin.com/urejey/10/edit

or

Html code would be :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("select").change(function () {

      var str = "";

       var maxlen = $(this).val().length;

      $(".products select option:selected").each(function () {

            str += $(this).text() + " ";

          });

    $("#hello").text("Selected : " + str + " - Length : " +  maxlen );

   if(maxlen > 15){

      $("#Chocolates").width(250);

   }

    })      

  .change();
 });

</script>
<style> 

 #Chocolates {    width:50px;  }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<p id="hello">Hello World</p>  

<div class="products">

 <select id="Chocolates">

  <option>Five Star</option>

  <option selected="selected">Dairy Milk</option>

  <option>Safari</option>

  <option>Kit kat</option>

  <option>Munch</option>

  <option>Perk</option>

  <option>Test Test Test Test Test </option>

  <option>Test Test Test Test</option>

  <option>Test Test Test</option>

</select>

</div>
```